# Bourbaki's definition of semidirect product

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-cohomology, group-extensions

This recess I'm off to learn about group extensions and the cohomological methods to characterize those extensions, but I'm a bit stuck on wraping my head around all the new concepts (I just finished a beginners course covering material on elementary number theory, algebraic structures of the integers, some basic abstract algebra - concerning only finite and abelian groups -, with hints on analytic number theory and deeper abstract algebra). I read the start of Serre's 1978 lectures *Groupes Finis* as a motivation, then moved on to Bourbaki's *Algebra*.

Bourbaki's encyclopedia was not hard to follow up to chapter 6, where extensions began popping up. The characterization of a extension was comprehensible, along with his demonstration that the direct product and the external direct product were extensions and their characterizations. But when he moved on to the (*omissed term* internal) semidirect product, I felt unsure on my understanding of the subject. Here's what I've got:

Bourbaki's definition, **external semidirect product**: If $G$ and $F$ are two groups and there exists a homomorphism $\pi$ of $G$ into $\text{Aut}(F)$ - (the automorphism group of F, which in my understanding clearly defines a action of $G$ on $F$, through the map $\phi :G\times F \rightarrow F$ where $\phi(g, f) \mapsto \pi(g)(f)$) - then the set $F \times G$ with the composition:
$$((f, g), (f',g')) \mapsto (f\pi(g)(f'), gg')$$
is a extension of G by F (written $F \times_\pi G$). With that proposition, we can describe all external semidirect product extensions of two groups $F$ and $G$ by looking at the possible homomorphisms of the automorphism group.

Now to the real question. Bourbaki's definition, **semidirect product**: $G$ is a semidirect product of the subgroups $H$ and $K$ if $H$ is a normal subgroup, if $K\cap H = \{e\}$ and $H.K = G$. First off, from my understanding the statement $H.K = G$ is referring to the property of complement subgroups, i.e., every element $g$ of $G$ can be uniquely written as $hk$ for some $h \in H$ and $k \in K$. That means $K$ has one and only one representative of each orbit of the equivalence relation defined by $H$, and that means $K$ is isomorphic to $G/H$. Now, Bourbaki proceeds: "Let $\pi$ be the operation of $K$ on $H$ by inner automorphisms of $G$. The mapping $(h, k) \mapsto hk$ is a isomorphism of $H \times_\pi K$ onto $G$".

I'm not sure I actually understand that last $\pi$ operation. If it defines a external semidirect product, it must be a homomorphism from $K$ to the automorphism group of $H$, so it must define a action of $K$ on $H$. When he mentions inner automorphisms of $G$, because $H$ is normal every inner automorphism of $G$ is a automorphism of $H$, and I guess the converse is also valid, so why couldn't $\pi$ be defined in terms of the group of automorphisms of $H$? Would it make it different? Does the set of inner automorphisms of $G$ and automorphisms of $H$ differ?

Comment: "Why couldn't $\pi$ be defined in terms of the group of automorphisms of $H$?" Could you elaborate on what you mean by this? We do define $\pi$ in terms of this group, namely as the function $K \to \mathrm{Aut}(H)$ defined by $\pi(k)(h) = khk^{-1}$.

Comment: @manthanomen sorry, I realize it is defined. My real question was, once it is defined solely by H and K, why does Bourbaki states that "$\pi$ is a operation of $K$ on $H$ by inner automorphisms of $G$"? There is a reason for not to exchange $G$ by $H$ on that phrase? Is it wrong to say "$\pi$ is a operation of $K$ on $H$ by inner automorphisms of $H$"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reference to "inner automorphisms" here is just to say that $K$ is acting on $H$ by conjugation.  That is, the homomorphism $\pi:K\to\operatorname{Aut}(H)$ is defined by sending $k$ to the automorphism $h\mapsto khk^{-1}$ (this maps $H$ to itself because $H$ is normal in $G$).  Note that you shouldn't say $K$ is acting on $H$ by inner automorphisms of $H$, because such an automorphism might not be an inner automorphism of $H$.  For something to be an inner automorphism of $H$, it must be of the form $h\mapsto khk^{-1}$ *for some element $k$ of $H$*, whereas here our $k$ is in $K$, not $H$.

(Also, automorphisms of $H$ and inner automorphisms of $G$ might be different; there is no reason that every automorphism of $H$ must be given by conjugation by some element of $G$, and there might be elements of $G$ which give different inner automorphisms on all of $G$ but which restrict to the same map on $H$.  All you can say in general is that there is a homomorphism from the inner automorphisms of $G$ to the automorphisms of $H$, given by restriction.)

Comment: But doesn't the definition of the external semidirect product work with any homomorphism $K \to Aut(H)$? There is no requirement stated that the automorphisms of $H$ mapped to must be given by conjugation by some element of $G$, but it just turns out that way, so how does this work?

Comment: There are many different external semidirect products of $H$ and $K$; we're specifically choosing the one where the homomorphism $K\to Aut(H)$ is given by conjugation in $G$.  Only that one will be isomorphic to $G$.